# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'segmentation_models_pytorch.unet' in Python 3.10 and 3.11

Tags: pytorch

I've trained a segmentation model using Python 3.8 environment and `segmentation_models_pytorch` aka `smp`. When I saved it and load in my prediction environment (Python 3.6 with `smp`) it worked with just

```
import torch

model = torch.load(path.join('models', model_name))
```

However it conflicts with `onnx` package (onnx requires newer Python). I've created new conda environment with Python 3.10 (another with Python 3.11). Now torch refuses to load the model with an error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'segmentation_models_pytorch.unet'`.

What is the right way to

1. install `torch` that supports `torch.load`
2. torch that knows about unet architecture
3. on the environment that supports onnx model conversion
4. doesnot require some old and very special version of Python (which causes conflicts with other packages)

   ```
   from os import path, environ
   import torch
   torch_model = torch.load(path.join('models', 'my_model.pth'))


   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\workspace\acne_prod\pytorch2onnx.py", line 3, in <module>
   torch_model = torch_load(path.join('models', 'test_model.pth'))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\sixty\anaconda3\envs\acne_prod_smp_onnx\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 809, in load
     return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\sixty\anaconda3\envs\acne_prod_smp_onnx\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1172, in _load
   result = unpickler.load()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\sixty\anaconda3\envs\acne_prod_smp_onnx\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1165, in find_class
     return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'segmentation_models_pytorch.unet'
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

Downgrade your SMP to the version you were training at. Or train your model on a fresh SMP if resourses allow. This way you avoid legacy Python issues.

Hence. This is NOT a pytorch issue. This is due to the change of the SMP models that caused issues with dackward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation_models is a different python package from pytorch and requires separate installation. !pip install -U git+https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch works for me on python 3.10.5 and later.

Comment: This is the first troubleshooting step. It didnot help in my case. See my solution below.